# Transform .parquet file varchar column to datetime in Azure Synapse

Tags: sql, parquet, azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-synapse

I am sending JSON telemetry data from our IoT Hub to Azure Data Lake Gen2 in the form of .parquet files. From the data lake I've then created a view in my Azure Synapse Serverless SQL pool that I can connect to and query data for reports.

```
CREATE VIEW DeviceTelemetryView
AS SELECT * FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://test123.dfs.core.windows.net/devicetelemetry/*/*/*/*/*/',
        FORMAT = 'PARQUET'
    ) AS [result]
```

This is what my view data looks like:
[image]

Most of these reports are based on date time ranges. Therefore I want to be able to write SQL queries that use my date time stamp.

**The Current Issue**

When I look at the current data type for the dateTimeStamp column, it defaults to varchar(8000) even though I believe my JSON is in the correct datetime format: *"2021-11-29T21:45:00"*. How can I transform this specific field to a datetime field in my view to run queries on it?

Answer (score 0):

> When I look at the current data type for the dateTimeStamp column, it defaults to varchar(8000)

I think you would have to look at the data type for that column in the parquet file, it's likely to be a string in your case. Sql interpret as a varchar(8000).

> even though I believe my JSON is in the correct datetime format: "2021-11-29T21:45:00".

Even if the timestamp format is correct, I think you'd have to tip system so it knows to cast that string to a datetime

> How can I transform this specific field to a datetime field in my view to run queries on it?

I'm not an expert in sql but I think you can convert a string to a timestamp using [cast and convert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```sql
CREATE VIEW DeviceTelemetryView
AS SELECT corporationid, deviceid, version, Convert(datetime, dateTimestamp, 126) AS NewDateFormat, data FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://test123.dfs.core.windows.net/devicetelemetry/*/*/*/*/*/',
        FORMAT = 'PARQUET'
    ) AS [result]
```

Comment: Yes convert worked! Although I had to update the convert part slightly as follows:
Convert(datetime, dateTimestamp, 126) AS NewDateFormat.
-- CONVERT Syntax:  
CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression [ , style ] ) .
IF you can update your answer I will mark as accepted